# huge mem kernel advice RHEL4

Tags: redhat, kernel

I've been asked to investigate adding extra memory (> 16gb) to a RHEL 4 server and moving to a huge mem kernel. The server is used for Oracle RAC.

Is it just a case of installing the hugh mem kernel and booting into ? or is it more complex than that ?

Any tips / gotcha's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really just a matter of installing the kernel and the related -devel packages. This is a 32-bit system, right? RHEL 4 is end-of-life in 6-8 months, and there may be some advantage to running a 64-bit OS if you can justify the move.

I have a 32GB ram CentOS 4 64-bit system here. I'm on kernel 2.6.9-100.ELsmp. It's been stable and I haven't had any issues, but will jump to the next revision of CentOS when it is released.